# MySQL order by multiple COALESCE(CAST

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 4 varchar fields that I need to order based on if the columns are empty.

So my table structure is:

```
start_price     reserve_price     buy_now_price    current_bid_amount
---------------------------------------------------------------------
50.00           50.00             empty (not null) (Null)
190             190               empty (not null) (Null)
150             150               empty (not null) (Null)
20              150               empty (not null) (Null)
550             600               empty (not null) (Null)
```

I have a order clause below but doesn't seem to order correctly. Currently the results are ordered 190, 150, 50, 20, 550.

> ORDER BY COALESCE(CAST(`al`.`current_bid_amount` AS SIGNED),
>   CAST(`al`.`buy_now_price` AS SIGNED), CAST(`al`.`start_price` AS
>   SIGNED), CAST(`al`.`reserve_price` AS SIGNED)) ASC

Basically I need to order by lowest first based on current_bid_amount, buy_now_price, start_price, reserve_price. So if current_bid_amount AND buy_now_price are empty use start_price. If current_bid_amount is empty but buy_now_price is not, use buy_now_price. If there is a value in current_bid_amount use that to order.

Many thanks.

Comment: now what is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well casting an empty string to a signed is 0. So your buy_now_price will probably override everything since it is empty but not null. You are then essentially not sorting since your coalesce will always evaluate to 0 for all your items.

```
mysql> select cast('' as signed);
+--------------------+
| cast('' as signed) |
+--------------------+
|                  0 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select cast(null as signed);
+----------------------+
| cast(null as signed) |
+----------------------+
|                 NULL |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I had a feeling that would have been the case. Is there a way to ignore the column if it is empty? or should I update my code to null it instead of leaving it empty?

Comment: Using null will make this simpler or you could do a coalesce on all values with a very large value and take the min or a negative value and take the max. However all of these will present issues since you won't be able to use any indexes. The better way would be to maintain an 'order column' that will never be null and represent the number you want to sort by and then you can also get indexing.

Comment: Thanks. I will apply your suggestion.